# Reduction over intersection of languages

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete, formal-languages

Given two languages $L1$ and $L2$, such that $L2$ is NP-Hard under polytime (many-one or Turing) reduction. Let $L=L1\cap L2$.

1- Is it true that if $L2$ is polytime (many-one or Turing) reducible to a third language $L3$, then $L$ is polytime reducible to $L1\cap L3$ ?

2- If $L \in$ P, what can it be concluded about the complexity of $L1$ ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: No.  For example, let *X* be an EXP-hard language, and let *L*=*L*<sub>1</sub>=*L*<sub>2</sub>={0*x*: *x*∈*X*} and *L*<sub>3</sub>={1*x*: *x*∈*X*}.  Then,

- Both *L* and *L*<sub>2</sub> are EXP-hard.  In particular, *L* does not belong to P and *L*<sub>2</sub> is NP-hard.
- *L*<sub>2</sub> is polynomial-time many-one reducible to *L*<sub>3</sub>.
- *L*<sub>1</sub>∩*L*<sub>3</sub> is the empty set.  Because *L*∉P, this implies that *L* is not polynomial-time Turing reducible to *L*<sub>1</sub>∩*L*<sub>3</sub>.

2: Nothing.  Let *X* be an arbitrary language and *Y* be an NP-hard language.  Let *L*<sub>1</sub>={0*x*: *x*∈*X*} and *L*<sub>2</sub>={1*y*: *y*∈*Y*}.  Although *L*<sub>1</sub>∩*L*<sub>2</sub> is the empty set and therefore trivially belongs to P, and *L*<sub>2</sub> is indeed NP-hard, this does not tell anything about the complexity of *L*<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: Right, I should have precised : in case of non-empty intersections.

Comment: @XavierLabouze: Requiring the intersection to be nonempty does not make any essential difference.  Please think about it.